# Error in solution of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I had the curve of a function,(eg $A\sin(x)+Bx+C=f(x)$) and i wanted to know A,B and C , so i took 3 points on the curve and solved $3$ equations and $3$ unknowns linearly.

The problem was when i took 3 points close to each other (eg $x=0.001 , 0.001008, 0.001009$) the answers would have a huge error.
i searched about this problem online, some pages suggested it was an error in the approximate matrix inversion but i guess they were wrong because i tried gaussian elimination and it didn't work either.

Another page suggested it's an error because of error in float numbers arithmetic but my friend (studying computer science) says it shouldn't make that much error in the final answers
So i wanted to know if this problem is a mathematical problem or a computational one?
for example consider the following points, the first set yields false answers and the second one yield correct ones
( first column is x , second is f(x) and third is answers if we solved it with these points)
[points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvr3C.png).

The error might not seem large in this case , but as the function grows more complex and the unknows increase, the error will increase

Comment: So if you used Gaussian elimination, why was it an approximate matrix inversion?

Comment: that's because the determinant of matrix approaches zero when points are too close and to find solution you basically need to divide by determinant. Any small error is magnified.

Comment: Please, provide the three points $x_i,f(x_i)$ for a check

Comment: Without knowing your points, I can't be sure, but your friend is very likely mistaken here. Cancellation can easily turn a minor absolute error into a huge relative error. Particularly if you are using single precision floats. I suggest trying it with double precision numbers (if you haven't) and with quad precision if you have. If you get much better results, then limited precision is the problem. But more generally, when setting up these problems, get the most widely separated points that you possibly can. Close always leads to numerical problems.

Comment: I am so sorry for the late replay , 
i am editing the post with points